# Spring can't autowire with custom UserService

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set up custom `OAuth2UserService` so that i can persist my own Custom User.

**Problem is:** i'm getting `lateinit property userRepo has not been initialized` the moment `loadUser` being invoked

So why wouldn't `@Autowired` initialize `userRepo`?

**Steps i did**:

1. Custom User entity

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User(
    @Id var id: Long,
    var username: String
)
```

2. Custom repo

```kotlin
@Repository
interface UserRepository: CrudRepository<User, Int>{
    fun findUserByUsername(username: String): User?
}
```

3. Custom service

```kotlin
@Service
class UserService : DefaultOAuth2UserService() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userRepo: UserRepository

    override fun loadUser(request: OAuth2UserRequest): OAuth2User {
        val oauth2User = super.loadUser(request)
        val user = userRepo.findUserByUsername(oauth2User.name)
            ?: throw UsernameNotFoundException(oauth2User.name)
        return CustomOAuth2User(
            user,
            oauth2User.authorities,
            oauth2User.attributes,
            oauth2User.name
        )
    }
}
```

4. Configuration

```kotlin
oauth2Login { oauth2 ->
   oauth2.userInfoEndpoint { endpoint ->
      endpoint.userService(UserService())
   }
}
```

Comment: So you are constructing an instance of `UserService` outside the scope of Spring and wonder why there is no dependency injection? You need to inject the Sprng Managed version and not create a new one yourself.

Comment: i guess you mean that i would need to make a @Bean instead of `UserService()` in `oauth2Login`?

Comment: No, your userservice is already an `@Service` which should be detected, you should be able to just inject it into your class of configure methoid.

Comment: oh, now i get it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The key was to inject service into configuration.

For those who wondering, here's the code:

```kotlin
@Autowired
private lateinit var userService: CustomUserService

@Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain =
        http.run {
            oauth2Login { oauth2 ->
                oauth2.userInfoEndpoint { endpoint ->
                    endpoint.userService(userService)
                }
            }
        }.build()
```